# How to include information from observations with mathematical inequalities in Ordinary Least Squares regression?

Tags: r, regression, least-squares, inequality

So, I was using Ordinary Least Squares (OLS) linear regression to build a model describing pond water level fluctuations in function of precipitation and potential evapotranspiration (PET) data. The dataset looks something like this:

[image]

With the first column describing a pond's measured depth (meter) at a given date, and the second the amount by which this depth changed over the time interval given by Start_date and End_date. The final two columns represent precipitation and PET over the same time interval.

Now, when a pond's depth decreased and was subsequently recorded to be zero (as with the 4th record), it could be that the depth decrease was limited by the amount of water present. In other words, the PET over this time period might have allowed for a greater depth decrease if there was more water present. The *potential* depth change is thus **not equal to the observed value, but equal to or greater than it.**

Is there a variant of OLS available which allows for the inclusion of information from these records (or inequality data in general) in the calculation of the regression coefficients? If so, is there a package available for R which has implemented this method?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but there is an entire area of statistics devoted to estimation under inequality (and other) constraints.  One good book on this topic is [this one](https://smile.amazon.com/Constrained-Statistical-Inference-Inequality-Constraints/dp/0471208272/) by Silvapulle and Sen.